# Make some methods in an API only available to a certain package - Java

Tags: java, api

I've these packages:

```
view
view.menu
view.modules
api
```

In package `api` I've a class `Api` (and a few others that are not relevant to my question). In the `view` modules and sub-modules I've a bunch of classes.

My Api class, as the name suggests, is my program's API, with methods used in the programs core and a few others that allow for someone else to customize the software on it's own way (adding modules, plugins, etc...).

So what I need to do is to find a way for the class `Api` to have methods X, Y and Z only available to all classes in the `view.modules` package while all the remaining methods in the `Api` class can be `public`.

I want to do this without moving the `Api class` to another package, and set the methods to `protected`, and avoiding at all costs to create another API class with just the X, Y, Z methods and importing that new API class. Can someone help me here?

Right now all methods inside class `Api` are defined as `public`

Answer (score 2):

As you note, package access would be the simplest way of handling this - anything at package level (anything specifically not marked public/private/protected) is only visible to classes in the same package. Another alternative would be to create 2 interfaces, one representing the public api and one for what you want the internal classes to see. Then you provide the Api through its public interface. It's still somewhat visible, as it would be possible to cast the interface to the concrete api, but at least then you'd know (or at least you should) that you're doing something risky.

Comment: API created in this way can be enforced using something like OSGi, but it is not part os standard Java. The package based access rules are very limited in Java.